# Oracle: MIN() Statement causes empty row returns

Tags: oracle

I'm having a small issue with sorting the data returned from a query, with the aim of getting the oldest updated value in dataset so that I can update only that record. Here's what I'm doing:

```
WHERE ROWNUM = 1 AND TABLE1.ID != V_IGNOREID 
AND TABLE1.LASTREADTIME = (SELECT MIN(TABLE1.LASTREADTIME) FROM TABLE1)
ORDER BY TABLE1.LASTREADTIME DESC;
```

It makes no difference as to whether the `ORDER BY` statement is included or not. If I only use the ROWNUM and equality checks, I get data, but it alternates between only two rows, which is why I'm trying to use the LASTREADTIME data (so that I can modify more than these two rows). Anybody have any thoughts on this, or any suggestions as to how I can use the MIN function effectively?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from (
-- your original select without rownum and with order by
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

**EDIT** some explanation

I think the `order by` clause is applied on the resultset after the `where` clause. So if the `rownum = 1` is in the same select statement with the `order by`, then it will be applied first and the `order by` will order only 1 row, which will be the first row of the unordered resultset.